# Add / Integrate iAd Into The App Using Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard, iad

I haven't worked with iAd ads and this is the first time i am going to implement them. Went though googling a lot of tutorials but they most of them are so old and done programmatically. What i want is to learn how to add them in the StoryBoard.

I can see the ad banner view in my StoryBoard. Although when i add the "Ad BannerView" by dragging it in my view controller and run it, it just crash saying uncaught exception. What else i need to do other than just dragging it in the StoryBoard, in order for it to work?

Comment: where you satisfied with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is to take a look at apple sample code. The iAd suite has many different approaches and one of the is integrating the iAd with story board. Here is the link to the sample code: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Also here is the link to the iAd class reference for further study. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html

I hope that clears the way for you to solve this issue.

Comment: can you link me to some other tutorial or guide since Apple's documentation always comes with a lot more detail than needed.

Comment: @AJ112, the sample code's link is in the answer. Just copy and paste the code into your class. Check the storyboard for the connections and you are good to go. But if you need a step by step, give me a few minutes I'll get you one.

Comment: @AJ112, as requested here is a link to a step by step tutorial for integrating iAd in storyboard: http://turtlehermit.com/?p=31 don't forget to check my answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put this into -viewDidLoad:

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

Don't forget to import the `iAd` Framework. If I was you I should use Google's `AdMob`.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW7) is a good link.

Comment: I am in the process of deciding whether to use AdMob or iAd.  What was you reason for recommending AdMob over iAd?